# EF Core SaveChangesAsync blocks call when there is an exception and not wrapped in try...catch

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I am trying to insert a record in a table with a foreign key. When the foreign key is valid it works fine, but when it's invalid, `SaveChangesAsync()` blocks call and UI stops responding. If I wrap it inside `try..catch` block then it throws an error and works fine.

If there is an error, why `SaveChangesAsync` doesn't throw it back?

```
Address Table
---------------------
Id    Street    City
1     Street A  City


container = new Container {
    Name = "Box",
    Size = 10
}
await _context.Container.AddAsync(container)

person = new Persion {
   Name = "A",
   AddressId = 2
   Container = container
}

await _context.Person.AddAsync(person);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync(true);
return container;
```

Thanks

Comment: If error is caught in catch block when local try catch is placed so error is definitely thrown, may be when there is no local try,catch then error is caught by upper layer try catch which doesn't throw it. Check console if UI has error or code has some other try catch in call stack

Comment: there is error thrown but what I would like to know why await _context.SaveChangesAsync(true) hangs and doesn't throw error when there is no try...catch. I was expecting it to throw exception rather than blockage but its blocking call which increase cup to 100% on azure.

Comment: I fail to reproduce your issue, is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Tao, i don't have demo but I will create one and upload it this weekend. Does above code work for you (did you get exception in UI/postman when you called api)?